# Частота RAM

Tags: ram

Подскажите на какой частоте работает оперативка?

данные брал из CPUZ.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Блин, извините не знал. Буду знать. но может кто тут знает?)

Comment: На первом скрине параметр DRAM Frequency.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- [**Вот**](http://www.a19.ru/products/25543-qumo-qum3u-4g1600k11r) ваша память, которая заявлена производителем, как `DDR3-1600.`
- У каждой плашки `RAM` фактически есть 2 параметра, которые влияют на производительность - это *частота* и *тайминги.*

> В данный момент времени ваша память работает на частоте `667Mhz`, что эквивалетно `DDR3-1333` (частота умножается на 2), а ее тайминги установлены как `9-9-9-24-33`.

- То, что указано на втором скриншоте - это значения `SPD`, иначе говоря, возможные установки частоты и таймингов, на которых данная плашка **гарантированно** будет работать.

> То есть, для вашей оперативной памяти заявлено, что ее можно устанавливать в любой из следующих конфигураций:
>
> - `(610Mhz @ 8-8-8-22-30)`
> - `(685Mhz @ 9-9-9-24-33)`
> - `(761Mhz @ 10-10-10-27-37)`
> - `(838 Mhz @ 11-11-11-30-41)`

- Обычно в плане производительности все варианты из `SPD` оказываются более-менее одинаковыми и вряд ли вы сможете заметить разницу между `DDR-1333 @ 9-9-9-24-33` *(ваши текущие настройки)* и, например, `DDR3-1600 @ 11-11-11-30-41` *(поддерживаемые вашей памятью настройки).*

> При желании вы можете зайти в `BIOS` и выставить там желаемую частоту и тайминги, однако, **лично я не вижу в этом смысла,** тем более, если учесть тот факт, что память у вас не `overclocker'ская`.

---

[**@Tim**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/3288/tim)

- Вы не поверите, но опция называется `DRAM Frequency` :)
- Оверклокерская память обычно делается *"с запасом прочности"* для разгона - насильного увеличения частоты и уменьшения таймингов. Стоит такая память, разумеется, дороже, однако в умелых руках разгон может дать ощутимый прирост производительности. [**Вот неплохой пример**](http://www.ocztechnology.com/ocz-ddr3-pc3-19200-blade-2-series-cl9-low-voltage-dual-channel.html) от `OCZ`.
- `Noname` память вроде вашей обычно работает сугубо на заявленных частотах и плохо поддается разгону, но зато дешевле стоит. Подъем напряжения, впрочем, никто не отменял.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать А кака опция отвечает в биосе за желаемую частоту? И что значит не overclocker'ская?

Извиняюсь за глупые вопросы, и спасибо за развернутые ответы :)

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать  DRAM Frequency, как то я не наблюдаю в биосе данной опции(

Да думаю 8Гб вполне хватит, че там разгонят то :)

Comment: @Tim

- Посмотрите вот [**это.**][1]

- `8GB` - это объем, а разгоном увеличивается пропускная способность, то есть, грубо говоря, скорость работы памяти.

[1]: http://www.google.ru/search?hl=ru&newwindow=1&safe=off&q=bios+ram+speed&qscrl=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&biw=1280&bih=939&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=BTk1UN6VMaWL4gSh44GYCw

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать окей, понял. Вопрос нет. Хотя остался 1-н. Все таки если не наблюдаю эту опции для опертивки в биосе, что делать? Обновление биоса поможет?

Comment: @Tim Посмотрите вот [**это.**][1]

[1]: http://www.google.ru/search?hl=ru&newwindow=1&safe=off&q=bios+ram+speed&qscrl=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&biw=1280&bih=939&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=BTk1UN6VMaWL4gSh44GYCw